# Yii2: How to render two views at the same time?

Tags: php, yii2, rendering

I have the **_form** view with a submit button that execute the **actionCreate()** function:

```
<?= Html::submitButton() ?>
```

When it's pressed it have to render/redirect two views:

- index.php in the same tab: It is rendered perfect.
- my_view.php in a **new tab**: I don't know how to do it.

Here it is the simplified actionCreate() function:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Persons();

    $this->render('_rpficha', [ 'model' => $model]);
    return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

Comment: New Tab in browser ?

Comment: you  should manage the onclick for submit button and do this in javascript  (not in PHP ) ..  calling the two url you need (one of this in new tab) .. server side is not possible  open a new tab ..  PHP don't know what happend in client  .. just render  html code

Comment: use `renderPartial`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript for this kind of client-side action.

In your view/index.php file:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs('
      setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
      }, 5000); //5 seconds timeout. set it to 0, if you want to do it immediately',
    \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
?>
```